# The API has been behind on and off today

Tags: bug, api

I'm using the SE android app which pulls data via the API (afaik).

All day, the data it's showing is out of date. I'll refresh the new question feed, and it will only show questions from like 10 minutes ago. I'll vote on a question, but it won't show that I voted, but when I try and vote again, it tells me that I already voted. I'll comment on a question, and the comment will never show up.

I know what I'm doing is actually going through though because if I check the main site, everything shows up as normal. It was happening around 4 hours ago, before I started work, and it's still doing it now on my break.

I just thought I'd let you guys know as your twitter doesn't mention anything about API problems recently.

(At least SO is behind. The other sites seem fine, although they don't have as much traffic so it's harder to tell).

Comment: I've experienced similar behaviour on the iOS SE app.

Comment: Still bad today too; although it was fine last night.